# replace NaNs in the merged dataframe based on the condition --(Python,Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes df1

```
ID     df1_Members
100    Eric
200    Chris
300    Jordan
400    Samantha
600    Audrey
```

df2

```
ID    df2_Members
100   Eric
200   Chris
300   Jordan
400   NaN
500   NaN
```

I am merging the dataframes`

```
df_merge=pd.merge(df1,df2,on='ID',how='left')
```

and the merged dataframe looks like this

```
ID  df1_Members  df2_Members
100  Eric         Eric
200  Chris        Chris
300  Jordan        Jordan
400  Samantha      NaN
600  Audrey        NaN
```

I want to replace NaN corresponding to ID 400 with "No Data" and ID corresponding to 600 with "ID doesn't exist" as ID 600 is not in df2

I am trying to do it like this,but it;s not working

```
if (df_merge['df2_Members']==np.nan) & (df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])):
    df_merge['df2_Members'].fillna('No Data',inplace=True)
#ID in df1 doesn't exist in df2
elif (df_merge['df2_Members']==np.nan) &(~df1['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])):
    df_merge['df2_Members']="ID doesn't exist in df2"
```

`

Comment: You questioni is confusing: ID 600 is in neither df's and df2 IDs 400 and 500 both are NaN, so the resulting df can't be what you show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_merge.loc[(df_merge['df2_Members'].isna()) & (df_merge['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])), 'df2_Members'] = 'No Data'
df_merge.loc[(df_merge['df2_Members'].isna()) & (~df_merge['ID'].isin(df2['ID'])), 'df2_Members'] = "ID doesn't exist in df2"

df_merge
```

Should return what you want

```
    ID  df1_Members df2_Members
0   100 Eric        Eric
1   200 Chris       Chris
2   300 Jordan      Jordan
3   400 Samantha    No Data
4   500 Audrey      No Data
5   600 Johnny      ID doesn't exist in df2
```

I added ID 600 as another name not present in df2